# for loop on multiple data frames with different lengths

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to add a new column to multiple data frames with different lengths.

For example, I have three data frames as below:

```
iris1 <- iris[iris$Species=="setosa" & iris$Petal.Width == 0.2,]
iris2 <- iris[iris$Species=="versicolor",]
iris3 <- iris[iris$Species=="virginica",]
```

I could add a column to an individual dataframe by using the following line:

```
iris1$Sepal <- rowMeans(iris1[, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")], na.rm = T)
```

So I tried to write a `for` loop to repeat this for multiple dataframe like below, but it just created a new dataframe `i`, and I'm having trouble figuring out writing the right loop.

```
iris.list <- list(iris1, iris2, iris3)
for (i in iris.list) {
  i$Sepal <- rowMeans(i[, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")], na.rm = T)
}
```

(I was searching on StackOverflow and noted that people also advised to use `apply` if possible instead of a `for` loop but couldn't get `apply` to work with my dataframes that have different lengths.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `lapply`:

```
iris.list <- lapply(iris.list, function(x) cbind(x, Sepal = rowMeans(x[, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")], na.rm = T)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way, but I like to use this method to make it easier to read when I come back to my code:

```
for (i in 1:length(iris.list)){
    currIris <- iris.list[[i]]
    currIris$Sepal <- rowMeans(currIris[, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")], na.rm = T)
    iris.list[[i]] <- currIris
}
```